# C equivalence of std::find

Tags: c

I am trying to implement the C++11 `std::find()` in my C application. I looked online and found this reference: [std::find in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)

My question, how can I use `string.end()`, `string.begin()` in C? Basically how would I use the function provided for `std::find()` with pure C?

So if I were to do:

```
std::string myString = "hello\n\n";
pos = myString.find("\n\n");
```

I would want the similar to this in C. How can I do this?

Comment: const char* c = "some string"; c[0] returns the beginning, strlen(c) returns the length of c, and c[strlen(c)-1] will return the last

Comment: maybe [`strstr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/)

Comment: [strstr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr)?

Comment: You can lean on `strstr` to implement your version of `find`.

Comment: @jameswoo Okay, I have no idea if you clicked the wrong question, or if you just didnt read what I wrote... what are you trying to say? I'm not asking anything with relevance to what you wrote. I'm asking how to implement a similar function to `.find()` from C++11 into C.

Comment: @AndrewPeters, I just saw your edit... sorry, thought you wanted the beginning and ending of the string, but I think you may have to traverse through the character array and match it with 'tokens' from what I remember (strtok)

Comment: @rpattiso I'm not looking for the function to do this, I know of strstr(), I'm interested in obtaining the source behind this, aka, the roots of it. It's what I meant with "pure C".

Comment: `std::find` and `std::string::find` are two different functions. which are you asking about?

Comment: `strstr` is part of glibc. It's open source. For example: https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~vcs-imports/glibc/master/view/head:/string/strstr.c

Comment: Well, wow, that sure is something. That's what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: `myString.find` is **not** `std::find`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C has the function [`strstr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/) which searched one string for another string and returns a pointer to the first character when found.  If the substring doesn't appear, it returns a NULL pointer

```
const char *my_string = "hello\n\n";
const char *nl = strstr(my_string, "\n\n");
size_t index = -1;
// now subtract the difference to get the index of the substring
if (nl != NULL) {
    index = nl - my_string;
}
```

Comment: Please check my last reply to the OP.

Comment: @AndrewPeters I'm confused, what do you mean by "the roots of it"? What do you imagine the "source" of `std::string::find` to consist of?

Comment: Well, I mean, I want to see what the source of strstr() consists of.

Comment: @AndrewPeters http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=string/strstr.c;h=045e878da3ca8f0cf4301d4a3d3c508286aa68db;hb=HEAD

Comment: @AndrewPeters you could also look at the [plan9 source](https://github.com/wangeguo/plan9/blob/master/sys/src/ape/lib/ap/gen/strstr.c), it's much simpler

Comment: Thank you Ryan, and everyone else for your time!